# Kotlin "is" operator for objects in when expression

Tags: kotlin

Lets imagine we have sealed class with data classes and objects inside:

```
    sealed class CarEvent {
         data class FilledFuel(val fuelAmount: Float) : CarEvent()
         data class ChangedPart(val part: CarPart) : CarEvent()
         object StartedEngine : CarEvent()
         }
```

Then we have `when` statement reducing events:

```
when(event) {
is CarEvent.FilledFuel -> { do something }
is CarEvent.ChangedPart -> { do something }
CarEvent.StartedEngine -> { do something }
}
```

The questing is: what is the most true approach for `StartedEngine` object:
compare it using `is` operator, or without `is` operator (using default `==` inside `when` statement).
Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: While there is a generic difference between `is` and `==` it doesn't matter here because StartedEngine is a single object which you're referencing on both sides of the `==` operator if you're using the equality method.

Comment: I'd go with `is` because it makes it clear your are doing the same thing as in the other two conditions, and it will still work if you decide StartedEngine needs to be a class after all.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any difference between these two?

Yes, `is` checks if something is an instance of a specific type, where as `==` will check if one object is the same as another

As an example:

```
 val foo = 5

 val result = foo is Int
```

This will always be true, because foo is a *type* of integer.

but if you consider

```
 val foo = 5

 val result = foo == 7
```

This will return false, correctly, because these two values aren't the same thing.

In your case, I don't think it would matter, but `is` would probably make more sense

Answer (score 2):

When has a syntatic sugar of evaluating what's inside parentheses versus each case
When you put nothing, it checks for equality and in other cases it checks what you put there

In case of objects, kotlin creates a class for them and creates a singleton `INSTANCE` and if you try to look at it from a Java point of view, when you put `is StartedEngine` it's like checking `event instanceof StartedEngine` and when put `StratedEngine` it's like `event.equals(StartedEngine.INSTANCE)`
so one of them check for type while the other checks for equality

On the other hand, object are strictly singletons which you cannot inherit, or override anything from them so it doesn't matter if you check for equality or `is` unless you've override `equals` in that object.

So they're not different in usage, nor in action. They are just different approaches.

```
sealed class A{
    abstract val name:String
    object AAA : A(){
        override val name get()= "AA"
        override fun equals(o: Any?) : Boolean {
            println("AAA equality call")
            return super.equals(o)
            }
    }
    object BBB : A() {
        override val name get()="BB"
    }
}
fun main() {
    val o : A = A.AAA
    
    when(o){
        is A.AAA -> println("o is AAA")
    }
    when(o){
        A.AAA -> println("o==AAA")
    }
}
```

But notice that if the `override fun equals` in AAA returned false, `o==AAA` wouldn't get printed also note that in second when, equals gets called and it prints `AAA equality call`

Output

```
o is AAA
AAA equality call
o==AAA
```